# Unit testing : Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Test is updated. Able to do some other tests using the same format. 
This is what I have so far
headers.test.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import   {Headers}  from './Headers';
import {configure} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';
import  renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('Headers', () => {

let tree;
let baseProps;
let mockauthKeyValues;
let mockheaderKeyValues;       
let mockaddNewKeyValue;

beforeEach(() => {
    baseProps = { // assing all of the props into MOCK
       authKeyValues: mockauthKeyValues,
       headerKeyValues: mockheaderKeyValues,
       addNewKeyValue: mockaddNewKeyValue
    }
})

 it('should render with all of the props', () => {  
    tree = renderer.create(<Headers {...baseProps} />)
    let treeJson = tree.toJSON()
    expect(treeJson).toMatchSnapshot();
    tree.unmount()
  });
});
```

I will be testing each props and make sure it renders without it.
I believe I am making at mistake when I mock all of this.props. Especially mockheaderKeyValues. I dont think i am setting up correctly.

This is the current code: headers.js

```
export class Headers extends Component {

 componentDidMount () {
if (this.props.authKeyValues == null) {
  this.setState({
    useDefaultData: false
  })
} else {
  this.setState({
    useDefaultData: true
  })
}
 }

generateKeyValues = () => {
if (this.props.headerKeyValues == null) {
  return (
    <KeyValue
      id={shortid.generate()}
      type='headers'
      addNewKeyValue={this.props.addNewKeyValue}
    />
  )
} else {
  let defaultKeyValues = Object.keys(this.props.headerKeyValues).map   ((headerKey, idx) => {
    return (
      <KeyValue
        key={headerKey}
        id={headerKey}
        type={this.props.headerKeyValues[headerKey].type}
        addNewKeyValue={this.props.addNewKeyValue}
        defaultData={this.props.headerKeyValues[headerKey]}
      />
    )
  })
  defaultKeyValues.push(
    <KeyValue
      id={shortid.generate()}
      type='headers'
      addNewKeyValue={this.props.addNewKeyValue}
    />
  )
  return defaultKeyValues
 }
 }

 render () {
 return (
  <div>
    {this.generateKeyValues()}
  </div>
)
```

}
}

Comment: This is obviously a mistake. `Workflow = shallow (<Router> <Workflow /> </Router>);` It's unclear what line the error refers to. Please, clarify this.

Comment: Sorry .This was a copy error.

Comment: Please, provide full error message. If it refers to specific line in the report, add this information. I have no idea what could be the meaning of `" " Is not defined` (is it empty variable name?)

Comment: ReferenceError: Workflow is not defined

Comment: Consider providing a way to replicate the problem. In the code you posted it's defined and cannot cause this error.

Comment: I just ran it again :   Invariant Violation: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router> and also ReferenceError: render is not defined

Comment: You need to use MemoryRouter. Check https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/testing.md

Comment: @estus I tried to add MemoryRouter into the code - And I will look up more info about it later.

Comment: Code updated @estus

Comment: Is `ReferenceError: Describe is not defined` the error you currently have? It's `describe`, not `Describe`. If you use `Describe` instead of `describe`, that's the problem.

Comment: @estus that was fixed already. I forgot to erase the top part when I update the question this morning. "It renders correctly'. What can I add on this test?

Comment: You need to change route params and assert how `render `works. `Component.instance().props.name` assertion doesn't serve a good purpose because you're testing the code you've written a line above.

Comment: @estus Any examples ? I'm following this video on youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kShTVHLWu9A . I will finish it later, hopefully it will cover different examples

Comment: I'd suggest to check Enzyme docs, they give a good idea how it's used to test components.

Comment: @estus i was able to do some of the tests by calling this.props and using almost the same format. Please take a look at the updated version

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem -
 Had to remove {} from import {Headers} since Headers import 2 more files , therefore it was not importing correctly

Comment: I was building my stories from the examples and this caught me out thanks!