# Storybook cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook

I have created a new component Navbar.jsx

```
import { Disclosure } from '@headlessui/react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import tacoPicture from '../public/lets-taco-bout-it.png'



function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}


export const Header = () => {
  return (
    <Disclosure as="nav" className="bg-white shadow">
      {({ open }) => (
        <>
          <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between h-16">
              <div className="flex items-center">
                <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                <Image src={tacoPicture} alt="Picture of the author" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
                
        </>
      )}
    </Disclosure>
  )
}
```

So, this needs to be described as a story. In my file Navbar.stories.jsx I do the following

```
import { Navbar } from './Navbar';

export default {
    title: 'Example/Navbar',
    component: Navbar,
  };
  
const Template = (args) => <Navbar {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});
```

And get the error:

[image]

I am new to storybook, however it seems to be a react issue, which I am also new to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934059/unit-testing-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-displayname-of-undefined/54356145#54356145

Answer (score 11):

Faced the same issue. What is the mistake I have done is using the wrong import.
So i change this,

```
import { Button } from './button';
```

Into this

```
import Button from './button';
```

I got the idea from @Katharina's answer. thanks...

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, I was importing a Navbar, my component's name is Header. Also there is a difference between `export default function () {}` and `export const x = () => {}`, which is crucial for importing.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. In my case, the problem wasn't in imports but in using *styled-components'* `css` attribute (using *babel-plugin-styled-components*).

```
<Button
  variant={"color"}
// this caused it
  css={`
    margin-right: 24px;
  `}
>
```

The workaround was to get rid of the `css` attribute by replacing the `Button` component with a new styled one. Like this:

```
const SubmitButton = styled(Button)`
    margin-right: 24px;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, I was working on an existing react library and making/editing things by hand. The solution was to find the index.ts in the src folder and add my new components to it manually.
Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import your component using this syntax:

```
import { Button } from './button';
```

You can use named export from your button component

export { Button }

otherwise you have to import it without the curly braces like so:

```
import Button from './button';
```

you can read more about named vs default exports here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

also this article has a nice explanation:

https://medium.com/@timoxley/named-exports-as-the-default-export-api-670b1b554f65